# Matching exact phrase in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

So i have a query like this:

```
{  
   "from":0,
   "size":20,
   "sort":{  
      "prices_count":"desc"
   },
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "terms":{  
                  "category_ids":[  
                     "3"
                  ]
               }
            },     
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"specs",
                  "query":{  
                     "bool":{  
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "match_phrase":{  
                                 "specs.model":"iphone-6s"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

My problem lies in the nested query part. the `specs.model` query matches not just documents with model `iphone-6s`, but the ones with `iphone-6s-plus`, I tried with `term` matching too, but then I get no results what so ever. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mapping-intro.html#_index_2):

> not_analyzed:
>
> Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it.

Set `model: not_analyzed` in mapping like:

```
{
  "model": {
    "type":     "string",
    "index":    "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

Then query with `term`.

Comment: this would work, but the keys like `model` are dynamic, can be any value, so I am now looking into dynamic_templates to solve that. but anyway your answer is correct!